# How to find html files running from server or not using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to javascript might be this question looks silly. How to check whether the html files are loading from local file system or server using javascript?

For example when I open the html files from my local system (/home/user/1.html) browser shows in url

`file:///home/user/1.html`

But if i load 1.html file into my local server then, if i access that file browser shows in url like below

`http://localhost/GUI/1.html`

I want to find whether files are loading from my server or local file system using java script.

Is there any way to find this using java script method.

Comment: `location.protocol`

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Can you provide some more details?

Comment: `console.log(location.protocol)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `window.location` object to do that.

use `window.location.protocol` property.

The following line of code will return true if the file is being served from the file system.

```
window.location.protocol == "file:";
```

It basically checks if the protocol being used is file or not.

Comment: This only check for the Html file loaded in the browser.. all consecutive Javascript file requests generated from html page will not get checked.

Comment: because the question asked is about HTML files only.